# Поменять стиль кнопки "читать далее... " на wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Есть сайт wordpress на теме Clean commerce.
Хочу поставить на кнопку "читать далее..." стиль от css чтобы она была нормально видна.
Она очень сильно сливается с текстом. Либо хотя бы поменять цвет.

Comment: Спасибо что сообщил. А какой ответ ты хочешь получить?

Comment: И что мешает Вам в каком-нибудь хроме нажать ctrl+alt+j, посмотреть какой к ней привязан класс, в каком файле он находится и на какой строке этой файла, и сделать её размером хоть с весь экран?

Comment: Здравствуйте ctrl+alt+j в хроме не работает. Не знаю почему. Можно поподробнее как найти класс и как найти фаил в котором этот класс находится.

Comment: ПКМ -> Посмотреть код

Comment: Так и дальше? .... можно подробнее посмотреть код хорошо а потом куда смотреть??????

Comment: Можешь что-то типа такого сделать
https://jsfiddle.net/t9h7gocn/